# how to reduce y-axis in matplot with same distance

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want this plot's y-axis to be centered at 38, and the y-axis scaled such that the 'humps' disappear. How do I accomplish this?

[image]

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s=['05/02/2019', '06/02/2019', '07/02/2019', '08/02/2019', 
   '09/02/2019', '10/02/2019', '11/02/2019', '12/02/2019', 
   '13/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '22/02/2019', 
   '23/02/2019', '24/02/2019', '25/02/2019']
df[0]=['38.02', '33.79', '34.73', '36.47', '35.03', '33.45',
       '33.82', '33.38', '34.68', '36.93', '33.44', '33.55', 
       '33.18', '33.07', '33.17']
# Data for plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 2))
for i,j in zip(s,df[0]):
    ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j+0.8))
ax.plot(s, df[0])
ax.set(xlabel='Dates', ylabel='Latency',
       title='Hongkong to sing')
ax.grid()
#plt.yticks(np.arange(min(df[p]), max(df[p])+1, 2))
fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain if this is what you're looking for but you can adjust the y-limits explicitly to change the scale, i.e.

```
ax.set_ylim([ax.get_ylim()[0], 42])
```

Which only sets the upper bound, leaving the lower limit unchanged, this would give you
[image: Y-axis limit control (upper)]

you can supply any values you find appropriate, i.e.

```
ax.set_ylim([22, 52])
```

will give you something that looks like
[image: Y-axis limit control (both)]

Also note that the tick labels and general appearance of your plot will differ from what is shown here.

---

**Edit** - Here is the complete code as requested:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
s=['05/02/2019', '06/02/2019', '07/02/2019', '08/02/2019', 
   '09/02/2019', '10/02/2019', '11/02/2019', '12/02/2019', 
   '13/02/2019', '20/02/2019', '21/02/2019', '22/02/2019', 
   '23/02/2019', '24/02/2019', '25/02/2019']
df[0]=['38.02','33.79','34.73','36.47','35.03','33.45',
       '33.82','33.38','34.68','36.93','33.44','33.55',
       '33.18','33.07','33.17']
# Data for plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 3))
#for i,j in zip(s,df[0]):
#    ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j+0.8))

ax.plot(s, pd.to_numeric(df[0]))
ax.set(xlabel='Dates', ylabel='Latency',
       title='Hongkong to sing')
ax.set_xticklabels(pd.to_datetime(s).strftime('%m.%d'), rotation=45)
ax.set_ylim([22, 52])
plt.show()
```

Comment: yes the secound image is really what i needed can you just share the compete code of it.

Comment: @itsvinit You just need to add the line `ax.set_ylim([22, 52])` after the line `ax.plot(s, df[0])` in your code